# cannot parse json using swift in iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to get value from json but it is giving this error

```
type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

My ViewController code is

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://resturl.com/rest/loginuser",
        parameters: ["password":uPwd,"username": uEmail,], encoding: .JSON).responseJSON() {
            (request,response, data,error) in

            let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error) as? NSDictionary // it is giving error here

            if let parseJson=jsonData{
                var result:String=parseJson[""] as String!;
            }
        }
```

I've searched internet but couldn't find any appropriate solution. Please guide me with this

Comment: let datastring = NSString(data: data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("JSON Retrieved \(datastring)") Print your JSON string to verify that you are receiving data from server. also try  print the error.

Comment: `.responseJSON` already convert it you doesn't need to convert it

Comment: @HamzaAnsari i want to display values from returned json.. how do i do that?

Comment: follow the answer below and you can get value using `pasreJson["someKey"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://resturl.com/rest/loginuser",
        parameters: ["password":uPwd,"username": uEmail,], encoding: .JSON)
.responseJSON { _, _, JSON, _ in

            if let parseJson=JSON{
              println(parseJson)
            }
        }
```

Comment: complier is giving error : Use of unresolved identifier parseJSON

Comment: How can i access some value in nested json array?

Comment: {
LoginUserResult: {
User: {
DisplayName: "Administrator"
Email: "admin@abc.com"
IsActive: false
IsDeveloper: false
IsExceeded: false
IsSystemAdmin: true
LanguageId: 0
License: null
Mobile: null
OUList: [1]
0:  {
CompanyId: 1
EmailAddress: ""
OUId: 2
OUName: "administrators"
}-
-
Password: null
PictureBytes: null
PicturePath: null
TelExt: null
UserId: 1
UserRoles: "1,"
Username: "administrator"
}-
mess: {
Status: 1
mess: ""
}-
}-
}

Comment: This is the output and i want to access mess value and displayname

Comment: i need to access it :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87958/discussion-between-hamza-ansari-and-usama).

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing the data will return in json format. So don't need to convert it in json format. So please use my code. Hope it will help you.
2. Second thing remove last semicolon(**,** ) which is extra in this line.

**["password":uPwd,"username": uEmail,]**

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://resturl.com/rest/loginuser",
                parameters: ["password": uPwd,"username": uEmail], encoding: .JSON).responseJSON() {
                    (request,response, data,error) in

                    if let jsonData : NSDictionary = data as! [NSDictionary : AnyObject]{
         // do stuff over here
        }
       else{
              println(data)
              println(error)
            }
     }
```

Comment: How can i access some value in nested json array?

Comment: it is also giving this error: Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on NSDictionary

Comment: now it is not returning any result, even code written under IF is not executing

Comment: @Usama It means your returning response is nil

Comment: @Usama Print error what problem you're getting for more info see my updated answer